# Using FreeMind mind-map software, how to space nodes?

Tags: freemind

I am using FreeMind from http://freemind.sourceforge.net/

I am trying to give my nodes some breathing room. In HTML, it would be equivalent to the node's padding, or margin, or line-height. Any way to apply such formatting in FreeMind?

[See this image](http://devstage.co/freemind_spacing.jpeg) to find maybe 2-3px of space between sibling node bubbles. I want to increase this amount of spacing, or as an alternative, the padding inside the node border.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://freemind.sourceforge.net/docs/features/0_8_0/Features%200.8.0.html

> Approaching the inner side (i.e. the side that is closer to the root node) of a 
>   node you'll notice that the mouse cursor changes and that a small ellipsis 
>   appears. In this area you can simply drag and move the node pressing 
>   the (left) mouse button. Moreover, if you press the control key simultaneously,
>   all nodes on the same level get a bigger or smaller spacing. In other words, 
>   the siblings of the moved nodes get more or less space in between.

Comment: Thanks for this!! I still cannot find a way to expand the size of the node, but this is immensely helpful in solving my original problem of margin between the nodes. +1 & accepted!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this for all nodes without having to do it manually each time is:

Go to format -> manage styles -> edit styles and set the "child gap" value (usually for the default style).

Answer (score 0):

ALT+mouse scroll expands or reduces the size of the node

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - he's trying to change the node "padding", not the size of the node itself.